# IGO 2017 P4 of Combinatorial Geometry

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math, planar-graphs, combinatorial-geometry, extremal-combinatorics

The following problem is from IGO 2017 (P4)

> $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_{100}$ are $100$ points on the plane, no three of them are collinear. For each three points, call their triangle clockwise if the increasing order of them is in clockwise order. Can the number of clockwise triangles be exactly $2017$?

-Proposed by Morteza Saghafian

**OBSERVATIONS-**

1. It cannot be solved by constructing a plane with these arbitrary points, simply because there are too many.
2. It is trivial to say that there **can** be a line join $2$ points such that all other $98$ points lie on the same side of this line. We $might$ use this fact.
3. We can make an ordered set containing all points in clockwise order. [We can construct such a set - prove by rotating an imaginary line around a pivot which is any point $Pi$ and then changing the pivot to the next point this line intersects and continuing to move it clockwise until it touches all $100$ points]
4. **BEST POINT** We can use a strong form of PHP which states that out of mn+1 elements in a sequence there exists a strictly increasing or decreasing subsequence of m+1 consecutive elements (assuming m<n)

Comment: See here [link](https://www.rl.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/4th_IGO_Problems-and-Solutions.pdf)

Comment: Wait, if you have a triangle with three vertices $P_i$, $P_j$, $P_k$ is clockwise if $i<j<k$? So for instance, $P_1, P_{20}, P_{43}$ is a clockwise triangle.

Comment: yes that's right @combinatorialist46Carey2

Comment: The Erdős–Szekeres theorem *could* be called a "strong form of the pigeonhole principle", like all other results in Ramsey theory, but it's still really weird that you're doing that.

Comment: Thank you for naming this theorem. I was intending to use in the sequence of clockwise arranged P's to find if the longest possible streak of continuously increasing i can equal to 2017. But unfortunately I later realised that it has flaws like 
1) the longest increasing sequence is not the only increasing sequence
2) It gives only consecutively increasing streak, which is a limitation we don't need- so whatever number of possibilities we get will be smaller that the total number which might include elements from skipped ranks
I still think there might be something similar that we can use?

Comment: I don't agree with the solution in Wizard0001's link. In fact, my first idea was to put the points on a circle as done by the solution. But I threw away this idea because there are many configurations that we can't do that. Take for example, n= 4 and the point $A_4$ is located inside the triangle $A_1A_2A_3$. Then, this solution can only be used for the case the $n$ points are vertices of a convex n-polygon.

Comment: @NN2 I agree with you that the question is vague about whether the configuration of points is fixed or can be chosen. Based on their solution, it would have been better phrased as "Does there exist a set of points with exactly 2017 clockwise triangles?" Perhaps there was something lost in translation from Persian to English.

Comment: Silly me, I was convinced that this does not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Let $ P_1, P_2, ..., P_{100} $ denote points on a circle. Initially, the count of clockwise triangles is set to zero. As the points move, the orientation of each triangle $ P_iP_jP_k $ undergoes a change by one each time point $ P_i $ passes through the line formed by connecting points $ P_j $ and $ P_k $. When the points eventually align in a complete clockwise order on the circle, the total number of clockwise triangles becomes $ \binom{100}{3} > 2017 $.

Since the count changes incrementally with each movement, there exists a specific instant when the number of clockwise triangles precisely equals 2017. This can be inferred from the fact that the count starts at zero and gradually increases, reaching the desired value at some point in the movement process.